# can anyone explain to me why same function can't get same result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def sum2(numbs):
    s = 0
    for x in numbs:
        print(x)
        s += x
    return s


def sum3(numbs):
    s = 0
    for x in numbs:
        print(x)
        s += x
        return s

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

function sum2 result is like below:

```
1
2
3
4
5
15
```

while sum3 is like below:

```
1
1
```

sum3 just change the function name and all other thing not changed.  Why is the result different?

Comment: You changed the indentation level of `return s` in `sum3`.  Did you mean to do that?

Comment: The indentation of `return s` is different. Indentation matters in Python.

Comment: They aren't the same function.

Comment: If you were unaware that indentation matters, what did you think defined the body of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

`return s` is in  the loop at `sum3`. Thus, loop is just working 1 time.

```
def sum3(numbs):
    s = 0
    for x in numbs:
        print(x)
        s += x
        return s #This return must be outside of the loop
```

Comment: thanks a lot,thank you

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of "return s" is different. It now occurs inside the for loop. You have to un-indent it so that this line is executed after the for loop ends.

Comment: please explain why this matters.

Comment: I got it,sorry for my stupid.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In `sum3`, you have the `return` inside the loop. In python functions, the moment a function hits a return, it returns the value and 'exits' the function. This means that your first function loops through the whole range before exiting, while the second only goes through the loop once

Comment: thanks you,very clear,good.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept one of the answers if it helped you out.